# Pointer from integer without a cast issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

in my `.h` file I defined:

```
BOOL *internetActive;
BOOL *hostActive;
```

and:

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *internetActive;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL *hostActive;
```

In my .m file I synthesize them and set the values:

```
   switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable:{
            self.internetActive = NO;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:{
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:{
            self.internetActive = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
```

but I get several warnings. First on every `= YES` I get

> Incompatible integer to pointer
>   conversion to BOOL (aka signed char)
>   from BOOL (aka signed char)

And right after the break statement I get an:

> Passing argument 1 of
>   setInternetActive makes pointer from
>   integer without a cast

What does that mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: It means that you’ve declared your instance variables/declared properties as pointers to `BOOL` and you’re using them as plain `BOOL`. As has been answered already, you don’t want pointers to `BOOL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is `BOOL internetActive` not `BOOL *internetActive;`

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a pointer to an object, so you can store them in `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` then use `NSNumber`.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *internetActive;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *hostActive;
```

In your *.m

```
switch (internetStatus) {
        case NotReachable:{
            self.internetActive = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:{
            self.internetActive = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:{
            self.internetActive = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];;
            break;
        }
    }
```